# Count all rows in column A containing "(CLOSED)" or "(DO NOT USE)"

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to return by Excel function  a count of all the rows in column A  where the text `(CLOSED)` or `(DO NOT USE)` is contained. All rows will contain other values too like so:

```
Row 1 = Nice Day (CLOSED)
Row 2 = Hello (CLOSED)
Row 3 = Cats & DOGS (CLOSED)
Row 4 = Cats (DO NOT USE)
```

so I need to search for the keywords `(closed)` or `(do not use)` in amongst the text.

Here's what I've tried to do so far but it doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A2:A3187,"(CLOSED)")
```

Please can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*(CLOSED)*")+COUNTIF(A:A,"*(DO NOT USE)*")
```

Comment: Of course this might double count rows if both text strings were in the same row - don't know if that's possible

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a wild card in your expression.
If you want to match `(CLOSED)` anywhere in the string:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*(CLOSED)*")
```

If you only want to match it at the end:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*(CLOSED)")
```